# code for visibility of listbox in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
  Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList2.SelectedIndexChanged
        MsgBox("OK")
        If (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex) = 1 Then
            ListBox1.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

I am facing problem in above code. I want to make listbox visible when the value of dropdownlist get changed. Does any one know that?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing

Comment: First, never use MsgBox in a web application.  Second, other than that the code looks amateur, but ok.  What is it doing that you find unexpected?

Comment: +1 to Dan-o for mentioning the MsgBox. @user2771784 - Remove If...EndIf, keep `ListBox1.Visible = True` only.

Comment: @afzalulh - You should post that as answer (with maybe a small explanation of why).

Comment: @Tim - thank you, I have posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dropdown's SelectedIndexChange will fire every time you select a different item. But you are making the ListBox visible only when SelectedIndex =1. Remove the SelectedIndex condition like this:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList2.SelectedIndexChanged
        'MsgBox("OK")
        ListBox1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

And ListBox will be visible each time DropDown selection changes.

**BTW:**   It is not clear how you are setting visibility of the listbox to false. Uou can post some markup and code to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the listbox to appear on ANY change in the value of the dropdownlist

```
Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList2.SelectedIndexChanged

Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

 cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "MyScript", "<script type=""text/javascript""> Alert("Ok"); </script>", False);
 ListBox1.Visible = True
    End Sub
```

However if you want to change when the user selects the first/second or nth item, you can use this

```
 Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList2.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

     cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "MyScript", "<script type=""text/javascript""> Alert("Ok"); </script>", False);


if DropDownList2.SelectedIndex = 0  //makes the listbox visible only when you select the first item, Use 1 for making the list box visible on the selection of the second item, so on and so forth.
     ListBox1.Visible = True
end if

        End Sub
```